# Selenium - How to find same elements in multiple forms in page

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a page(s) where there are multiple forms and all have the same type of fields. I need to find all values of "Detection Date" and compare it with the input.
My question is how can I get the datetime from all the Detection Date elements? A page might have 5-6 Detection Date values

I tried this but didn't work

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'CellHeaderRight') and   text()='Detection Date']"));
 System.out.println("Number of Date Fields " + list.size());
```

It gave me  0

```
<form id="idFrmUpdatePlateNumber" onsubmit="UpdatePlateNumber(1); return false;" 
action="" method="post" ,="" name="frmUpdatePlateNumber">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1" style="background-color:#f9f9f9;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="CellHeaderRight" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">Detection Date:</td>
<td>1/20/2015 10:56:31 PM</td>
.....
</tr>
<form id="idFrmUpdatePlateNumber" onsubmit="UpdatePlateNumber(2); return false;" action="" method="post" ,="" name="frmUpdatePlateNumber">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1" style="background-color:#f9f9f9;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="CellHeaderRight" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">Detection Date:</td>
<td>1/20/2015 10:55:02 PM</td>
```

This is additional HTML

```
<div id="idDivSearchResults" class="" style="display: block;">
table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="border-width:1px; border-style:inset; background-   color:#d0d0d0; padding:10px;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<b>Event Details</b>
<form id="idFrmUpdatePlateNumber" onsubmit="UpdatePlateNumber(0); return false;" action="" method="post" ,="" name="frmUpdatePlateNumber">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1" style="background-color:#f9f9f9;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="CellHeaderRight" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">Plate Number:</td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="CellHeaderRight" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">Detection Date:</td>
<td>1/20/2015 11:59:59 PM</td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression you've presented would match the `td` element with `Detection Date:` text, while you need the next `td` element. Use [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//td[contains(@class, 'CellHeaderRight') and .='Detection Date:']/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Note that there was also a `:` missing after `Detection Date`.

You may also check for the text starting with `Detection Date`:

```
//td[contains(@class, 'CellHeaderRight') and starts-with(., 'Detection Date')]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

---

Also, you would probably need to *explicitly wait* for a form to show up before searching for detection dates:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("idFrmUpdatePlateNumber")));

// find dates
```

If the search results are inside the `iframe`, you need to *switch to it* first:

```
driver.switchTo.frame("Frame_ID_or_Name");

// find dates
```

Comment: Thanks.. But I still get 0... I used this List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'CellHeaderRight') and text()='Detection Date']/following-sibling::td[1]"));

Comment: @user3749141 oops, found another problem, missing `:` in the xpath - please recheck.

Comment: My bad... added that.. but still getting 0.. :-(

Comment: @user3749141 I've added one more option. Also, a sanity check, let's count forms: `//form[@id='idFrmUpdatePlateNumber']` - how many do you get?

Comment: aghhh!.. that is the crux of the problem.. doing a count of the forms returns 0...  I have edited my post to show more HTML code

Comment: @user3749141 I think you need to explicitly wait for a first form to appear first - I've updated the answer - try it out.

Comment: How do I get into the form? There isn't any separate frame for the results

Comment: The form is never found .. ! org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: idFrmUpdatePlateNumber

Comment: @user3749141 are there any `iframe` or `frame` elements on the page?

Comment: Sorry.. I explicitly switched to the default frame  and it worked..I assumed wrongly that since the frame was same I didn't have to do a switch to.... thanks for your help.. appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get the elements such as `<td>1/20/2015 10:55:02 PM</td>`, if it is always the second child of the tr, then you could use the xpath:

```
*//tr[td[text()="Detection Date:"]]/td[2]
```

This will find the tr element which contains a td element with the text of detection date, and take the second elements of that tr element.

As well, this [website](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) is a very useful resource for testing xpath and css selectors.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to also include the class in the xpath, you could say: `*//tr[td[text()="Detection Date:"][@class='CellHeaderRight']/td[2]`

Comment: Thanks but the problem it seems is the form is not reachable

Comment: I should ask a few questions to troubleshoot. 1. Is the form you are looking for contained within an iframe? 2. What occurs when you run the test with the xpath of just div[@id='idFrmUpdatePlateNumber']? 3. Is it possible that the page just hasn't finished loading yet when you try to get the values?

Comment: Sorry.. I explicitly switched to the default frame  and it worked..I assumed wrongly that since the frame was same I didn't have to do a switch to.... thanks for your help.. appreciate it...